# MySQL query to get common duration

Tags: mysql, sql

I am unable to solve this query problem for fetching common duration of two different IP addresses in which both are in OFF status.

Cases in the below sample data

> 1 (Simple case) - IP address "10.0.1.2" is remains OFF for 00:10:10 to 00:20:00 and "10.0.1.3" is also OFF in this duration, so the common duration of OFF for both is 00:10:10 to 00:20:00.
>
> 2 (Problematic)- IP address "10.0.1.2" is OFF for 13:00:00 to 13:25:00 and if we check it with other IP address, it is OFF for 12:55:00 to 13:20:00. So, the common duration in both are 13:00:00 to 13:20:00.

Sample data:

```
ID   IP address  Status   Time
----------------------------------
1    10.0.1.2    OFF      00:10:00
1    10.0.1.2    ON       00:20:00
1    10.0.1.2    OFF      11:00:00
1    10.0.1.2    ON       11:20:00
1    10.0.1.2    OFF      13:00:00
1    10.0.1.2    ON       13:25:00
1    10.0.1.2    OFF      14:05:00
1    10.0.1.2    ON       14:10:00
1    10.0.1.2    OFF      15:35:00
1    10.0.1.2    ON       15:45:00
1    10.0.1.3    OFF      00:10:00
1    10.0.1.3    ON       00:20:00
1    10.0.1.3    OFF      11:05:00
1    10.0.1.3    ON       11:25:00
1    10.0.1.3    OFF      12:55:00
1    10.0.1.3    ON       13:20:00
1    10.0.1.3    OFF      17:10:00
1    10.0.1.3    ON       17:15:00
1    10.0.1.3    OFF      15:00:00
1    10.0.1.3    ON       16:45:00
```

Output:

```
ID   IP addresses       Status  Time
-----------------------------------------
1    10.0.1.3,10.0.1.2  OFF      00:10:00
1    10.0.1.3,10.0.1.2  ON       00:20:00
1    10.0.1.3,10.0.1.2  OFF      11:05:00
1    10.0.1.3,10.0.1.2  ON       11:20:00
1    10.0.1.3,10.0.1.2  OFF      13:00:00
1    10.0.1.3,10.0.1.2  ON       13:20:00
1    10.0.1.3,10.0.1.2  OFF      15:35:00
1    10.0.1.3,10.0.1.2  ON       15:45:00
```

Comment: Yeah i know its not free coding service, I have already tried this, that's why I am putting my  question here. If you need what I have done on this , I will share that also.

Comment: Yes, we need what you have done on this. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Barmar : I have tried this on ms-excel. is that would be ok for you?

Comment: Not really. We want to see your attempted SQL solution. Then we can tell you what you did wrong, and how to fix it. That way you learn from your mistakes. If you haven't tried to do it in SQL, then you seem to be asking us to write it for you.

Comment: Okay.. I will convert my excel attempts in SQL and then update question

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Hi Abhishek. I've added a bounty to this to award an existing answer. As per the above conversation, would it be possible for you to add the SQL you were working on prior to asking? It's a bit late now in terms of helping answerers, but it's good practice, and your new readers will appreciate the effort. `:-)`

Comment: If you were not using MySQL that doesn't have window functions I would direct you to an excellent article [Packing Intervals by Itzik Ben-Gan](http://blogs.solidq.com/en/sqlserver/packing-intervals/).

Comment: Hi Abhishek, would you reply to my message above, please? I can see you are signing in from your profile.

Comment: @halfer: ok..I will add my SQL attempts.

Comment: (Mark for follow-up 30th May).

Comment: No attempts added, voting to close.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a starter for you.

- I reduced the IP address to an int for readability, `ip`.
- I changed status to text. It should be boolean and if MySQL does not have that, then maybe char(1) or int with CHECK constraint.
- You need to consider some constraint or unique index to guarantee status switching and preventing turning it on while it is already on (turning it on multiple times)?
- Declare appropriate indices to speed up the query. Otherwise it's *quadratic complexity*.

```
CREATE TABLE foo (ip int NOT NULL, status text NOT NULL,
    ts time NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ip, status, ts));

INSERT INTO foo VALUES
(2, 'OFF', '00:10:00'),
(2, 'ON',  '00:20:00'),
(2, 'OFF', '11:00:00'),
(2, 'ON',  '11:20:00'),
(2, 'OFF', '13:00:00'),
(2, 'ON',  '13:25:00'),
(2, 'OFF', '14:05:00'),
(2, 'ON',  '14:10:00'),
(2, 'OFF', '15:35:00'),
(2, 'ON',  '15:45:00'),
(3, 'OFF', '00:10:00'),
(3, 'ON',  '00:20:00'),
(3, 'OFF', '11:05:00'),
(3, 'ON',  '11:25:00'),
(3, 'OFF', '12:55:00'),
(3, 'ON',  '13:20:00'),
(3, 'OFF', '17:10:00'),
(3, 'ON',  '17:15:00'),
(3, 'OFF', '15:00:00'),
(3, 'ON',  '16:45:00');
```

Assuming you have Common Table Expressions CTE's in MySQL (you didn't specify the version either, among other things).

If you don't have CTEs, then just copy and replace all references to the CTE (`off` in this case) and give it a name.
The last example will not use `WITH`.

```
WITH off AS
(SELECT ip,
        ts "off_from",
        (SELECT ts FROM foo
         WHERE ip = a.ip AND a.ts <= ts AND status = 'ON'
         ORDER BY ts ASC LIMIT 1) "off_until"
 FROM foo a WHERE status = 'OFF'
)
SELECT * FROM off;
```

Which gives

```
 ip | off_from | off_until
----+----------+-----------
  2 | 00:10:00 | 00:20:00
  2 | 11:00:00 | 11:20:00
  2 | 13:00:00 | 13:25:00
  2 | 14:05:00 | 14:10:00
  2 | 15:35:00 | 15:45:00
  3 | 00:10:00 | 00:20:00
  3 | 11:05:00 | 11:25:00
  3 | 12:55:00 | 13:20:00
  3 | 17:10:00 | 17:15:00
  3 | 15:00:00 | 16:45:00

WITH off AS
(SELECT ip,
        ts "off_from",
        (SELECT ts FROM foo
         WHERE ip = a.ip AND a.ts <= ts AND status = 'ON'
         ORDER BY ts ASC LIMIT 1) "off_until"
 FROM foo a WHERE status = 'OFF'
)
SELECT *
FROM off x
INNER JOIN off y
ON  x.off_from <= y.off_from AND y.off_from < x.off_until
AND x.ip <> y.ip ;

 ip | off_from | off_until | ip | off_from | off_until
----+----------+-----------+----+----------+-----------
  2 | 00:10:00 | 00:20:00  |  3 | 00:10:00 | 00:20:00
  2 | 11:00:00 | 11:20:00  |  3 | 11:05:00 | 11:25:00
  3 | 00:10:00 | 00:20:00  |  2 | 00:10:00 | 00:20:00
  3 | 12:55:00 | 13:20:00  |  2 | 13:00:00 | 13:25:00
  3 | 15:00:00 | 16:45:00  |  2 | 15:35:00 | 15:45:00
```

And to get take the minimum and maximum of the times use

```
WITH off AS
(SELECT ip,
        ts "off_from",
        (SELECT ts FROM foo
         WHERE ip = a.ip AND a.ts <= ts AND status = 'ON'
         ORDER BY ts ASC LIMIT 1) "off_until"
 FROM foo a WHERE status = 'OFF'
)
SELECT x.ip "ip_a", y.ip "ip_b",
       greatest( x.off_from, y.off_from ) "off_from",
       least( x.off_until, y.off_until ) "off_until"
FROM off x
INNER JOIN off y
ON  x.off_from <= y.off_from AND y.off_from < x.off_until
AND x.ip <> y.ip ;
```

to yield

```
 ip_a | ip_b | off_from | off_until
------+------+----------+-----------
    2 |    3 | 00:10:00 | 00:20:00
    2 |    3 | 11:05:00 | 11:20:00
    3 |    2 | 00:10:00 | 00:20:00
    3 |    2 | 13:00:00 | 13:20:00
    3 |    2 | 15:35:00 | 15:45:00
```

Without `WITH` (copy paste and name the CTE).

```
SELECT x.ip "ip_a", y.ip "ip_b",
       greatest( x.off_from, y.off_from ) "off_from",
       least( x.off_until, y.off_until ) "off_until"
FROM
(SELECT ip,
        ts "off_from",
        (SELECT ts
         FROM foo
         WHERE ip = a.ip AND a.ts <= ts AND status = 'ON'
         ORDER BY ts ASC LIMIT 1) "off_until"
 FROM foo a WHERE status = 'OFF'
) x
INNER JOIN
(SELECT ip,
        ts "off_from",
        (SELECT ts
         FROM foo
         WHERE ip = a.ip AND a.ts <= ts AND status = 'ON'
         ORDER BY ts ASC LIMIT 1) "off_until"
 FROM foo a WHERE status = 'OFF'
) y
ON  x.off_from <= y.off_from
AND y.off_from < x.off_until
AND x.ip <> y.ip ;
```

For the inner select with `LIMIT 1` consider an index on `(ip, status, ts)`.

For the join, maybe an index on `ts` can be used by your DBMS. The CTE (`WITH` clause) would materialize the virtual table once only. That may not apply with copy-pasting the CTE several times (two times here).

This is supposed to be a rough starter for you. It's by far not perfect or the best solution. There may be other better ones.

Comment: Tip: if you want to render a block of code immediately after a list, and the block is not to be indented as being part of the last list element, then put a `<!-- HTML comment -->` after the list to break it up. However if you want to render a block of code _inside_ a list element, then indent it twice (i.e. eight spaces instead of four). HTH!

Comment: By way of encouragement for your great answers, I have added a bounty to this question. Perhaps that will make up for the various times an OP has apparently not made use of your help `:-)`.

Comment: @halfer Oh wow - Thank you very very much! IMO thinking about some DB problem posted on SO takes quite some time to understand and then to solve a bit more. On the other hand, clicking the accept button and upvoting can be done really quick - yet sometimes people don't appreciate the effort taken by posters here :( At least give the posters some virtual (credit) points, if it solves a problem. Maybe I should choose to answer questions from new users less and prefer more experienced users (100 points+). So how can i be awarded the bounty? What do i need to change? Thank you again so much!

Comment: I would say that if you believe the OP has made an excellent effort in their question, and they have shown what they have tried, then that will protect you against help vampires to a good degree. That said, it's not a perfect strategy: I saw in your history that you'd answered a question from a 1K+ user, and are still having difficulty getting an acceptance. Unfortunately that happens, and although I do not like it when people do not accept, answer acceptance is considered as optional here.

Comment: Bounties can only be awarded 24 hours after they have been placed, so I can award it this time tomorrow at the earliest. However I tend to let bounties run for their duration (7 days) as it gives a good question or good answer some exposure. You don't need to do anything (the system will remind me to award it when the bounty begins to expire).

Answer (score 2):

One method is to get time as seconds using `TIME_TO_SEC()` and calculate the difference in a stored procedure:

```
Create table common_duration (
ip varchar (10),
start_time time,
end_time time
)

CREATE PROCEDURE `comm_time`()
    BEGIN
    DECLARE curs1 CURSOR FOR SELECT `IP`, TIME_TO_SEC(`time`) as time, STATUS FROM TABLE;
    DECLARE ip varchar(20);
    DECLARE iptime time;
    DECLARE ipstime time;
    DECLARE ipstatus varchar(10);
    OPEN curs1;
    FETCH curs1 INTO ip,iptime,ipstatus;
    if (status='ON')
    insert into `common_duration`(ip, start_time, end_time) values(ip, ipstime, iptime);
    else
    ipstime=iptime;
    endif;
    CLOSE curs1;
    SELECT t1.ip SEC_TO_TIME(t1.end_time-t1.start_time) as time_duration FROM `common_duration t1, `common_duration t2
    WHERE t1.time_duration= t2.time_duration
          AND t1.ip != t2.ip;
    End
```